# Detect when JS Fade has completed, and run more code

Tags: javascript, html, slideshow, fade

I have the following setup for a simple automatic slideshow.

```
<div id="slideshow1" class="slideshow_container"/>
<!-- Image 1, this one is behind the div below -->
   <div id="slideshow2" class="slideshow_topimage"/>
      <!-- Image 2, the one on top which will do all of the fading -->
   </div>
</div>
```

So, first of all "slideshow2" will fade to opaque, once faded, it's background image will swap. 
It will then fade back into view and "slideshow1" will swap to the next image.

Below is all of my JavaScript, how would I make the "fadeEffect" function continue to run the code to swap images once its finished fading?

```
//Fetch images for slideshow
function slideshowPrep(container) {
    var http = getHTTPObject();
    http.onreadystatechange = function() 
    {                   
        if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200)
        {
            //Split images
            var imgs = http.responseText.split(",");
            imgs = cleanArray(imgs);
            preload(imgs);
            slideshowGo(imgs);
        }
    }
    http.open("GET", ROOT_DIR+"/php/returnImages.php");
    http.send();
}
//Manage the image swapping and execute the fading
function slideshowGo(imgs,next) {
    var next = 0;
    var con1 = doc("slideshow2").style.backgroundImage; //"url('')";
    fadeEffect.init('slideshow2',0);

}
var fadeEffect = function() {
    return{
        init:function(id, flag, target) {
            this.elem = doc(id);
            clearInterval(this.elem.si);
            this.target = target ? target : flag ? 100 : 0;
            this.flag = flag || -1;
            this.alpha = this.elem.style.opacity ? parseFloat(this.elem.style.opacity) * 100 : 0;
            this.elem.si = setInterval(function(){fadeEffect.tween()}, 20);
        },
        tween:function() {
            if(this.alpha == this.target) {
                clearInterval(this.elem.si);
            }else{
                var value = Math.round(this.alpha + ((this.target - this.alpha) * .05)) + (1 * this.flag);
                this.elem.style.opacity = value / 100;
                this.elem.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + value + ')';
                this.alpha = value; 
            }
        }
    }
}();
```

**Edit:**
Okay, added what I believe to be a callback, but the alert does not execute...?

```
//Manage the image swapping and execute the fading
function slideshowGo(imgs,next) {
    var next = 0;
    var con1 = doc("slideshow2").style.backgroundImage; //"url('')";
    fadeEffect.init('slideshow2',0,0,function(x) {
        alert(x);
    });
}
var fadeEffect = function() {
    return{
        init:function(id, flag, target, callback) {
            this.elem = doc(id);
            clearInterval(this.elem.si);
            this.target = target ? target : flag ? 100 : 0;
            this.flag = flag || -1;
            this.alpha = this.elem.style.opacity ? parseFloat(this.elem.style.opacity) * 100 : 0;
            this.elem.si = setInterval(function(){fadeEffect.tween()}, 20);
        },
        tween:function() {
            if(this.alpha == this.target) {
                clearInterval(this.elem.si);
                this.callback("callback?");
            }else{
                var value = Math.round(this.alpha + ((this.target - this.alpha) * .05)) + (1 * this.flag);
                this.elem.style.opacity = value / 100;
                this.elem.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + value + ')';
                this.alpha = value; 
            }
        }
    }
}();
```

**Edit:**

Still not working, changed the callback to this like you said:

> this.callback = "callback";

The alert in the slideshowGo function simply doesn't fire:

```
fadeEffect.init('slideshow2',0,0,function(x) {
        alert(x);
    });
```

Comment: add this.callback = callback in your init

Comment: Updated my post again

Comment: could be a scope issue, try fadeEffect.callback = callback and then call fadeEffect.callback("fire");

Comment: Nope, is it due to the fact that the fadeEffect isn't a normal function?

Comment: Have added a jsfiddle to my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't this the point where the fade effect has finished?

```
        if(this.alpha == this.target) {
            clearInterval(this.elem.si);
            // fire callback or increment loop counter or doNext()
            if (typeof cb === "function"){
                 // you can also pass any args that 
                 // may be useful to a callback here
                 cb();
            }
        }
```

[Simplified jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chim/94Z93/2/)

Comment: Yeah, but my main issue is fetching the images all over again. I would have to pass the "imgs" array to the fade function and then back to the slideshowGo function wouldn't I?

Comment: Use a callback function for the cases when you need it

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to use a jquery fadeout, it would just be the following for the fadeout:

```
    $('#slideshow2').fadeOut( "slow", function() {
        // Animation complete. perform the next action...
    });
```

http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/

Comment: I dislike  jquery as good as it is, i'm not exactly learning anything by using it...

Comment: Still, if there's something out there like jquery that's already tried and tested it's a massive time saver... I agree that it's always good not to rely on a framework though but to use it as a helper

Comment: Once I know how to do it myself, I might use the framework. I find it pretty pointless whilst I teach myself though as I'm not learning how it works or how to do something similar myself.